# how to turn a for loop into a .each() function using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to convert for loop to .each() function... here is the code

```
for (var i in json_obj){
    if(i > 0){
        $("output").empty();
        output += "<td>" + json_obj[i].id + "</td><td>" + json_obj[i].firstname + "</td><td>" + json_obj[i].lastname + "</td><td>" + json_obj[i].fullname + "</td><td>" + json_obj[i].email + "</td><td>" + json_obj[i].reg_data + "</td><br />";
        output += ("<tr></tr>");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$.each(json_obj, function(i, object){
  if(i > 0) {
    $("output").empty();
    output += "<td>" + object.id + "</td><td>" + object.firstname + "</td><td>" + object.lastname + "</td><td>" + object.fullname + "</td><td>" + object.email + "</td><td>" + object.reg_data + "</td><br />";
    output += ("<tr></tr>");
  }
});
```